# Invariant under topologies under action of $S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology

Suppose we a set X of n elements. How many topologies invariant topologies do we have on X under the action of $S_n$ on it, i.e if $\tau$ is invariant under $S_n$ iff  $M \in \tau$, then $\sigma(M) \in \tau$, where $\sigma \in S_n$.

I think it is 2 the discrete and indiscrete topology as we can always permutate the singletons of the topologies, but only topology which doesn't have singletons is the indiscrete topology and the topology which contains all its singleton is the discrete topology. I don't have formal proof of this however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\tau$ has a open set $A\ne \varnothing$ and $A\neq X$ then there are $a\in A$ and $b\not \in A$. The permutation $\sigma =(a\, b)$ send $A$ to $B=A\backslash \{a\}\cup \{b\}$, so $B$ is open.

Thus $B\cap A=A\backslash \{a\}$ is open and has $1$ element less than $A$. Keep doing so, we get a singleton which is an open set and $\tau$ is the discreet topology.

Comment: Why is B open ?

Comment: $B=\sigma(A)$, and $\tau$ is invariant under $S_n$.

Comment: Yeah I didn't notice that..

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it's only the discrete topologies and the indiscrete topologies. This follows from the fact that if every subset of size $k<|X|$ is in a topology on $X$, then the topology is discrete. Proof: By induction. Base case is trivial.

Let $S$ be any set of size $k-1$ and suppose every subset of size $k$ is in the topology. Choose any subset $U$ of size $k$ which contains $S$. Since $|X|$ is strictly larger than $k$, there is some element $e$ which is not in $U$, so define $V=S\cup\{e\}$. But then $U\cap V=S$.

Since $S$ was arbitrary, the topology contains all sets of size $k-1$, and so by induction it is discrete.

Comment: I don't follow your proof. "Base case is trivial" -- What is the base case here?

Comment: The base case is when you plug $k=1$ into the statement: "If every set of size $1$ is in a topology on $X$, then the topology is discrete".

Comment: Then why do you "suppose every subset of size $k$..." and show the statement for $k-1$?

Comment: Ah, I see the confusion. We're not showing the *statement* for $k-1$, we're assume the antecedent for the $k$ case, and proving the antecedent for the $k-1$ case. In other words, we assume that every subset of size $k$ is in the topology, and prove that therefore every subset of size $k-1$ is in the topology. Then the inductive hypothesis says that in this situation, we know the topology is discrete, and we are done. (My plan is actually the same as yours; just with some formalism around it.)

Comment: So the base case is $k=1$, and what does your argument imply?

Comment: Consider the $k=4$ case. I know all size-4 subsets are in there, so I take an appropriate intersection to show that all size-3 subsets are in there, and (then the induction gets me) that all size-2 subsets are in there, and so all size-1 subsets are in there, and so it's discrete.

Comment: I see that your idea is similar to mine now. It may be your wording is a little different (than mine).